# Making functions with the output of a ReplaceAll

Tags: functions

I'm trying to make a function from the variable "replace" of next code:

```
reactions = <|a -> αu #1/(ku + #1), b -> μu #1, c -> Du #1,
    d -> αv #1/(kv + #1), e -> αi #2 #1/(ki + #1), 
   f -> μv #2, g -> Dv #2|>;

replace = {a, c, d} /. reactions
```

I want to Apply the output of "replace" to a list of numbers:

```
replace & @@ {1, 2}
```

But this returns the next output without any solution:

```
{(33.25 #1)/(450 + #1), 0.035 #1, 0.4 #1}
```

Why this doesn't work?

If a try to become "replace" in a Function, it also doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make each element of `replace` a function by wrapping it with `Function`.

```
functions = Function /@ replace
```

> {(αu #1)/(ku + #1) &, Du #1 &, (αv #1)/(kv + #1) &}

Use `functions` with  `Through` to apply all functions to the same argument:

```
Through[functions@1]
```

> {αu/(1 + ku), Du, αv/(1 + kv)}

Use `Map` to apply this function to a list of arguments:

```
Through[functions@#] & /@ {1, 2}
```

> {{αu/(1 + ku), Du, αv/(1 + kv)},
>   {(2 αu)/(2 + ku), 2 Du, (2 αv)/(2 + kv)}}

Alternatively, map `Function` on `reactions` before you create `replace`:

```
reactions2 = Function /@ reactions;
replace2 = {a, c, d} /. reactions2;
Through[replace2@#] & /@ {1, 2}
```

> same result

Answer (score 2):

Using your original definitions:

```
fn = Function @@ {replace};

fn[2]
```

> ```
> {(2 αu)/(2 + ku), 2 Du, (2 αv)/(2 + kv)}
> ```

```
fn /@ {1, 2}
```

> ```
> {{αu/(1 + ku), Du, αv/(1 + kv)}, {(2 αu)/(2 + ku), 2 Du, (2 αv)/(2 + kv)}}
> ```

```
fn @ {1, 2}
```

> ```
> {{αu/(1 + ku), (2 αu)/(2 + ku)}, {Du, 2 Du}, {αv/(1 + kv), (2 αv)/(2 + kv)}}
> ```